# String matching in R to return "does not contain" results

Tags: regex, r

I would like to drop all rows in my data frame where column A contain either a "_" or "(" or ")" and where column D does not contain "InService".

I believe you can use grep or grepl for the contains section but I don't know how to tie it into my expression below.

```
Atoll <- read.csv("ATOLL_TABLE20160803_084232.csv")
AtollInService <- Atoll[(Atoll$MILESTONE=="InService" & grep(???)),]
```

Below is an example of the excel file I am importing, please note I've hidden a few columns since the data is spread across many fields.

```
NOMINAL_ID     MILESTONE
WW_4752 (MD)    Planned
WW_4752 (MD)    Planned
WW_4752 (MD)    Planned
LX0022 (OZ)     Planned
LX0022 (OZ)     Planned
LX0023          InService
LX0023          InService
LX0023          InService
LX0023          InService
LX0023          InService
LX0023          InService
```

And below is what I am looking to achieve:

```
NOMINAL_ID      MILESTONE
LX0023          InService
LX0023          InService
LX0023          InService
LX0023          InService
LX0023          InService
LX0023          InService
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Comment: `with(Atoll, Atoll[grepl("[_()]", A) & !grepl("InService", D), ])`

Comment: @MichaelChirico I used the following code but I am getting the same results as the original file with no filtering, have I missed something? 'Atoll <- read.csv("ATOLL_TABLE20160803_084232.csv", fill = TRUE, sep = ",", colClasses = c("factor", "factor", "factor", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "factor", "NULL", "factor", "factor", "integer", "integer", "integer", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "integer", "numeric", "factor", "numeric", "numeric", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "numeric"))'
'AtollInService <- with(Atoll, Atoll[grepl("[_()]", "Atoll$NOMINAL_ID") & !grepl("InService", "Atoll$MILESTONE"), ])'

Comment: I can't help you more without reproducible date

Comment: Sorry @MichaelChirico here is a link to a stripped down version of the file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzkBEqPfozOOdWZDeC1nYW1OVHM/view?usp=sharing) Please note I renamed the file to 'Atoll' for simplicity so my read.csv above needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grepl`; see `?grepl`.

```
Atoll <- read.csv("ATOLL.csv")

Atoll_filtered <- 
  with(Atoll, Atoll[grepl("[_()]", NOMINAL_ID) & 
                      !grepl("InService", MILESTONE), ])

nrow(Atoll)
# [1] 65

nrow(Atoll_filtered)
# [1] 36

head(Atoll_filtered)
#      NOMINAL_ID MILESTONE
# 1 WW_4664 (KNP)   Planned
# 2 WW_4664 (KNP)   Planned
# 3 WW_4664 (KNP)   Planned
# 4 WW_4664 (KNP)   Planned
# 5 WW_4664 (KNP)   Planned
# 9 WW_4665 (KNP)   Planned
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChirico, I was using quotes for the names of the columns which was messing everything up. Thanks for your help.